# Getting API javadoc while hovering

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Because I was lacking disk space on my system disk, I moved the Android SDK to a second one. Globally, it was not a problem for Android Studio except that it doesn't display the javadoc when I hover on the code.

The "Show quick documentation on mouse move" is checked so the help window appears, and the description of the function being hovered is displayed in a floating window. The problem is when I try to display this help in a browser window by clicling on the blue arrow pointing up, I only get an error indicating the doc can't be fetched (Android Studio tries to get it from the internet instead of using the local version available on my disk)...

Any idea about what I have to do to recover this important functionnality?

Comment: Why don't you download the documentation locally using the SDK manager?

Comment: That's already done! I can already see it's content in the floating window, but not in a browser window. That's a problem because navigating in a browser window is much easier than in the floating one.